# When i add image to my post , i got this : (70007)The timeout specified has expired: mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client

Tags: php, apache2, prestashop, mod-fcgid, ispconfig

I am working with apache2 and using ispconfig 3.1 for web panel. 
I published prestashop 1.6.1.7 on my server .
When i reboot my server , i could add an image but for next image i got this problem again!
I did everything for solving this problem :

- change required max items (ex:max_execution_time , ....) in php.ini
- even set paramater in my fcgid.conf for max items
- change permissions for my prestashop directories
- check setting for image in prestashop

But at the end i got this problem again!
Could you please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Hello. This error you got is a server error right? Could you please activate DEBUG MODE in Prestashop and publish if some other error appear. Good luck.

Comment: I activated the debug mode , but i got no errors

Answer (score 0):

Edit file:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf
```

Try to adjust the website default settings for fcgi in

```
/usr/local/ispconfig/server/conf/vhost.conf.master
```

The master template gets applied to a website when you change a value in that site in ispconfig and then click on save. Please note that it takes a minute until the configuration is written to disk.

As an alternate solution you can also try to change the following configuration in php.ini file of your server.

```
max_execution_time = 1500; or more as per your need
max_input_time = 1500; or more as per your need
post_max_size = 500M; or more as per your need
```

Comment: Hi . I did what you said but i got the same error again!  I install on the same server a Wordpress  and it works well but i do not know what is the problem with prestashop! thanks.